# covariant basis for spherical coordinate system

Tags: tensors

In this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoffel_symbols#In_Earth_surface_coordinates) the third covariant basis vector in the spherical coordinate system (when using the physics $r, \theta, \varphi$ convention) is:

$$ e_{\varphi} = R \cos \theta (-\sin \varphi \quad \cos \varphi \quad 0)$$

Is this wrong? In both [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1985964/christoffel-symbols-for-spherical-polar-coordinates) and [Pavel Grinfeld's textbook](https://grinfeld.org/books/An-Introduction-To-Tensor-Calculus/Chapter9.html) (section 9.2.8) it appears that it should be $\sin \theta$ instead of $\cos \theta$.

Comment: Depends how $\theta$ is defined. If, as usual, it's angle from the north pole, then it's obviously wrong since when $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we have $e_\varphi = 0$.

Comment: Wikipedia says $\theta$ is the latitude. As we know the north pole as at latitude $90^\circ$ while in physics convention it is $\theta=0\,.$ Nothing is wrong.  Just a different $\theta\,.$